# Libgdx applyforce to actor to finger touch/moving direction

Tags: drag-and-drop, rotation, libgdx, actor

Consider I am pulling bus by finger touch and drag movement. Road is not straight. so if i am moving my finger along the road . the Bus should follow the finger along with some rotations that will be needed when there is turn.

First finding the distance between actor and touchpoint and if it is less then
I am simply setting the position of bus (Actor) to touch points location.

now it feel like i am dragging bus.

Now I have to handle the rotations.

can i apply force to actor towards touchpoint??
can i handle rotation of actor towards touchpoint ...

simple logic in my mind is dragging finger means drawing a line..now i have to match center line of the actor to dragged line..

please give me hint regarding handling the rotation of bus.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you just want the bus to follow a path like a normal bus would follow a road.

You can rotate a body by applying torque to it. That means you will use applyForce(...) and not use the center of mass as the point to apply the force to.

But you don't want to apply a force and make it move towards a certain target point like that, because that would just look weird and you would need some special handling for realistic car physics (for topdown you can see that here http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/top-down-car).

Better just calculate a path yourself and calculate the angle between different points on that path. Then use body.setTransform(...) and set the position and the rotation of the bus manually. That's how you would do it as well, if you wouldn't have any physics engine.

Comment: Thanks for reply,

yes,You got my question. I can use Box2D but i don't know how to add Actor in body in LibGdx. so using simply actor and calculating manually.

You have mentioned above that use body.setTransform(..) , can i apply it on simple actor??.

or I have to treat my actor(bus) as something else.

Comment: Actors have nothing to do with Box2D. They are part of the scene2d API, not Box2D. Unless you implemented a custom "PhysicsActor" (which extends Actor and has a Body as a property). This new Actortype would override translate(x,y) for example and delegate that to the body by using setTransform(...) on the body. This new Actortype will be your bridge between scene2d and box2d.

If you don't even use a body for your bus yet, then forget about everything so far and instead of using setTransform use setPosition/setRotation on the Actor.